# Problem opening archive file(.exe) in Ubuntu 8.04 using archive manager

Tags: ubuntu-8.04

I have installed both rar and unrar using apt-install but I am still not able to use archive manager for opening the archive file.. I have also tried installing p7zip(p7zip-full and p7zip) but no improvements...

However, when I use command-line for extracting the files from the archive using unrar or rar the command executes successfully...

The error that is displayed in the command-line of the Archive Manager:

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Is there any other open source software I should install for viewing the contents of the archive or what else should I install to view the same in the archive manager..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you open RAR files using File Roller? If not, then there might be something wrong with your setup (should work after installing unrar). [Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller) do not mention SFX at all as supported/unsupported format.

Comment: Yes it is opening RAR files, but not .exe, the archive file